# How can I programmatically detect which apps caused phone to wake up?

Tags: android

Looking for a way to collect a statistics on phone wake ups. And then uninstall that stupid app which does that every 10 minutes on my phone.

**Update**: Tried battery apps, they are crap. They show that phone wakes up every 5-15 minutes, but tell me nothing why. They also show how much each app drained, but it always less than 5%.

So I looking for a way to collect this stats and do some analytics with that.

**Update II**: Looks like there are battery managers that do the job (GSam Battery Monitor for example), and with a bit of reverse engineering I hope I'll find, how they collect statistics.

Comment: I tried dozen of battery apps, by they are not conclusive. Lost about 65% of battery in 8 hours with phone sleeping. From all apps system took about 30%, other apps less than 5% each.

Answer (score 1):

This option is not programmatic, but you could use it to find out what's causing the problem.

In command line, with device connected, type:

```
adb shell dumpsys power
```

You can find more details about the `dumpsys` command here:

- [How can I see which wakelocks are active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780280/how-can-i-see-which-wakelocks-are-active)
- [What's the Android ADB shell "dumpsys" tool and what are its benefits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201659/android-adb-shell-dumpsys-tool)
- [Using dumpsys commands in the Android adb shell](http://wrightrocket.blogspot.com/2010/12/useful-commands-in-adb-shell.html)
- [Dumpsys - AOSP](http://source.android.com/tech/input/dumpsys.html)