# Accessing wakelock statistics in android application

Tags: android, power-management, wakelock

I am writing a power management application for Android.

I want to be able to access wake lock statistics in my application. Details like which wake locks are active now, how many of them are partial, full..etc, which wake lock prevented device from entering sleep and so. Is there a way i can do this..?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way i can do this..?

You are welcome to track your own app's own use of `WakeLock` yourself. You do not have access, from an app, to data about other apps' use of `WakeLock`.

Developers can use `adb shell dumpsys power` to see what `WakeLock`s are outstanding, as is illustrated in [this SO question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780280/how-can-i-see-which-wakelocks-are-active).

Comment: Thanks, but i have seen apps that provide wake locks information. Like BetterBatteryStats. How do you think they are doing it?

Comment: @Kishan: Probably by exploiting some security hole. I will work on getting the hole closed. Thanks for pointing this out!