# Is there a way to find programmatically what application holds you mobile awake after screen is OFF?

Tags: android, android-wake-lock

Is there a way to find programmatically what application holds you mobile awake after screen is OFF?

I need to detect what application holds awake, to make some statistics for the user?

For example on Feb 11, 13:44 app X holds awake for 20 minutes. etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a repost of [How can I see which wakelocks are active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780280/how-can-i-see-which-wakelocks-are-active), which is a realtively thorough discussion on wakelocks. Essentially, you can gather the wakelock info from the dump of running `adb shell dumpsys power`.

Comment: thx, but I think it needs the phone to be rooted. And it is not good for me.