# Will "START_STICKY" service prevent android from sleeping?

Tags: android, android-service, wakelock

If I start a service with "START_STICKY" mode (android was **awake** when this service was **started**), does this make sure that the service will keep running (in the sleep mode / prevent android from sleeping) even if the screen is off and the device is not plugged in?

In other words, once a service is started in "START_STICKY" mode, is it required to acquire a wake lock to make sure android doesn't sleep? Or, is it guaranteed that once such a service is started, android will not sleep until the service is stopped by the app?

Comment: read this document to learn more about it.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> does this make sure that the service will keep running (in the sleep mode / prevent android from sleeping) even if the screen is off and the device is not plugged in?

No.

> is it required to acquire a wake lock to make sure android doesn't sleep?

Yes.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply Mark! Actually when I started a media player with this service, and the song was set to loop, I waited for entire hour with the screen off, and the song was still playing. So I thought maybe, that was the case. (no other wake locks from my app).

Comment: @MohitSingh: No, `START_STICKY` only says "restart my process after you terminate it". Something else may be holding a `WakeLock`. **`adb shell dumpsys power**` should tell you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780280/how-can-i-see-which-wakelocks-are-active

Comment: Thanks again, this will really help me :)

Comment: by the way, I just confirmed it - it says this while the track plays: `Wake Locks: size=1
PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK              'AudioMix' (uid=1013, pid=0, ws=WorkSource{10107})`

Comment: @MohitSingh: It's possible that comes from the media playback. You might try commenting that bit out, terminate your existing process, confirm that you're not associated with a `WakeLock`, then run the revised app.